# Grid Graph Laplacian Second Eigenvalue

Tags: graph-theory

> Find an upper and a lower bound on the second eigenvalue of the laplacian of the Grid graph on $n^2$ vertices.

It occured to me that the Grid graph is actually a multiplication of two Path graphs but I am not able to prove it. Am I wrong?
I also tried finding an eigenvector that is orthogonal to the all $1$ vector in order to use Courant-Fischer to find a lower bound for the second eigenvalue, but I can't find a formula for such a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid graph is the Cartesian product of two copies of the path $P_n$.
The eigenvalues of the Laplacian of the Cartesian product of two graphs
are the sum of the eigenvalues of the Laplacians of the graphs. So the second largest eigenvalue of your grid is the sum of the largest and second largest eigenvalues of the Laplacian of the path $P_n$. Hence your eigenvalue is $4+2\cos(\pi/n)+2\cos(2\pi/n)$. (The Laplacian eigenvalues of $P_n$ are the adjacency eigenvalues of $P_{n-1}$ plus 2.)